# Why it is forbidden to import several Apex Methods at once in LWC module?

Tags: lightning-web-components, import

I have Apex Controller Class, say, `LWCController` and several methods inside of it, let's say `Method1`, `Method2`, `Method3`, `Method4`, `Method5`.

[Documentation says that](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.apex) to

> Use default import syntax to import an Apex method via the
>   @salesforce/apex scoped packages.

[image]

[Default import syntax allows to imports several items from the same module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

> ```
> import { export1 , export2 } from "module-name"; 
> import { foo , bar } from "module-name/path/to/specific/un-exported/file"; 
> import { export1, export2 as alias2 , [...] } from "module-name"; 
> import defaultExport, { export [ , [...] ] } from "module-name";
> ```

[image]

I am trying to import all of them simultaneously at the same line

```
import {Method1, Method2, Method3, Method4, Method5 } from '@salesforce/apex/LWCController';
```

And I receive the following errors

> ```
> === Deploy Errors PROJECT PATH  ERRORS    
> N/A           [Line: 2, Col: 118] LWC1501: @salesforce/apex modules should have both class and method names.
> N/A           LWC1513: @salesforce/apex modules only support default imports.
> ```

Comment: `import {Method1, Method2, Method3, Method4, Method5 } from '@salesforce/apex/LWCController';` how will SF know which alias to use for which method? WHat if there are 10 methods in class and you importing 5 ?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Default aliases could be used, Method1 for Method1 etc. If I import 5 methods, I want these 5 methods be available with default aliases, for the other 5 methods I don't care.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like here by "default" imports meant only imports which import one item from the module, so I have to use the following workaround.

```
import Method1 from '@salesforce/apex/LWCController.Method1';
import Method2 from '@salesforce/apex/LWCController.Method2';
import Method3 from '@salesforce/apex/LWCController.Method3';
import Method4 from '@salesforce/apex/LWCController.Method4';
import Method5 from '@salesforce/apex/LWCController.Method5';
```

which is nasty but the only available workaround.

Comment: It's not a workaround, it is intended behavior. The reason **why** is because the methods can be bound by metadata, like they are in Visualforce, so you can't accidentally delete them from the class.

Comment: If I was able to import several methods at once, they would be still bound by metadata, but my code would look much more elegant and clean

Comment: I know what you're saying, but that's not how it was engineered. They also didn't give us the wildcard import syntax, either. Maybe we'll get it in a future release? At any rate, we're stuck with what we have.

Comment: I agree that we are stuck with what we have.