# Is it there anyway to get multiple imports from the a Apex controller using using a single import statement using LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

I would like to have one statement to get multiple apex controller methods:

```
import { LightningElement, track, wire } from 'lwc';
import {
    getThis,
    getThat,
    cancelThis,
    cancelThat
} from '@salesforce/apex/MyCustomController';
```

But the above gives me this error:

> LWC1513: @salesforce/apex modules only support default imports.
>   [Line: 10, Col: 7] LWC1501: @salesforce/apex modules should have both class and method names.

**Question**

1. Is this even possible?
2. If so, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Don't think this is supported each import has one to one mapping with server side controller, what benefit do you see with `one statement to get multiple apex controller methods`?

Comment: Same question with answer https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/254343/why-it-is-forbidden-to-import-several-apex-methods-at-once-in-lwc-module

Comment: Marking as duplicate as mentioned by @Boris: Possible duplicate of [Why it is forbidden to import several Apex Methods at once in LWC module?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/254343/why-it-is-forbidden-to-import-several-apex-methods-at-once-in-lwc-module)